# Svelte's a11y linter rules on a custom web component

Tags: accessibility, svelte

I have a svelte app where I am using a custom web components library. I've got a custom button which uses  internally and handles a11y support.

But when I pass in an `on:click` handler to my custom component, I am getting this a11y error

```
A11y: visible, non-interactive elements with an on:click event must be accompanied by an on:keydown, on:keyup, or on:keypress event.svelte(a11y-click-events-have-key-events)
```

Is there any way that I can inform svelte-check that my `<custom-button>` is a11y supported?

Comment: What is your <custom-button> a subclass of?

Comment: The custom-button comes from a package that I've been adding declarations for in a `components.d.ts`.  I wonder if there's a way to specify the subclass through type declarations